# Mongoose Geospatial Query Error: unknown top level operator: $near

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

With this schema:

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");
let GeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');
    let dogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        //Some code omitted
        location: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point,
            coordinates: [Number],
        },
        //Some code omitted
    });
dogSchema.index({"location": "2dsphere"});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Dog", dogSchema);
```

And this kind of input:

```
{
  "created" : ISODate("2018-03-04T02:17:58.868Z"),
  "name" : "Babee",
  "breed" : "Puddle",
  "age" : 11,
  "owner" : ObjectId("5a9b5756a1e44812d109f191"),
  "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [-118.4912, 34.0195] },
  "__v" : 0
}
```

I perform this query:

```
 Dog.find({
        $near: {
        $geomentry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [-118.4452, 34.0689],
                }
            }
        }, function (error, result){
            //Some code omitted
   });
```

With this index:

```
index: '2dsphere'
```

Which produces this error:

```
{ MongoError: unknown top level operator: $near
    at queryCallback (/Users/varun/Desktop/Programing/Woof/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:223:25)
    at /Users/varun/Desktop/Programing/Woof/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'unknown top level operator: $near',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $near',
  code: 2,
  codeName: 'BadValue' }
```

How do I fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

It appears I had an an error with indices being dropped  [Link](https://medium.com/@juha.a.hytonen/beginner-s-foes-in-testing-with-mongoose-and-mongodb-d9214712bb3a)

Comment: Try `Dog.find({location:{
        $near: {
        $geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [-118.4452, 34.0689]
                }
            }
        }}, function (error, result){
            //Some code omitted
   });`

Comment: @Veeram I ran it again with the changes you made, it worked but returned an empty array. I have data seeded in the array. I ran it on the MongoShell with this code `db.dogs.find({
     location: {
         $near: {
             $geometry: {
                 type: "Point",
                 coordinates: [-118.4452, 34.0689]
             }
         }
     }
 }).pretty();`  That worked. I have included the results in the question.